# Resource not found

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working within a simple ROS workspace where I have two packages.

I have included in my workspace (as a new package, "**robotic_moveit_config**") a configuration generated by **MoveIt setup assistant**. My question is about this particular package.  The configuration generated by **MoveIt setup assistant** already creates different launch files.

I can build the workspace correctly, and then using **roslaunch**  I can successfully run, for example.

roslaunch  robotic_moveit_config demo.launch

and so I can test simple planning scenarios in **rviz**.

At the same time, I am trying to write some simple motion planning programs.

zahid_test_workspace

```
src  
--  my_test_pkg
--   ur5_moveit_config 
      
      -- include
      -- src
      -- launch    
         -- smp.launch
```

Here, when I try to issue

```
roslaunch ur5_moveit_config smp.launch
```

I receive the following error.
Resource not found: ur_description

Although before running roslaunch, I do the following

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source devel/setup.bash
```

The strange thing is that, other day, I was able to launch my program.
Here is the launch file that I am using.

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find ur5_moveit_config)/launch/demo.launch"/>
<node name="ur5" pkg="ur5_moveit_config" type="ur5" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

thanks,

Zahid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339600/resource-not-found/) by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-12-10**:
Did you build your workspace before calling `source devel/setup.bash`? Can you please add the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2019-12-10**:
I build the package using,
`catkin clean`
followed by
`catkin build`
then I issued
 `source devel/setup.bash`

The complete error is follows

```
Resource not found: ur_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/zahid/Desktop/IMPLEMENTATIONS/zahid_test_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

and the output from echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
/home/zahid/ws_moveit/src/ros-moveit-arm/moveit_plugin:/home/zahid/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials:/home/zahid/ws_moveit/src/ros-moveit-arm/my_arm_xacro:/home/zahid/ws_moveit/src/panda_moveit_config:/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2019-12-10**:
I explicitly added the following path

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/zahid/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

to the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Then, to confirm I issue `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and I receive the following output

```
/home/zahid/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot:/home/zahid/Desktop/IMPLEMENTATIONS/zahid_test_ws/src/my_test_pkg:/home/zahid/Desktop/IMPLEMENTATIONS/zahid_test_ws/src/ur5_moveit_config:/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

The directory `ur_description` is found under `/home/zahid/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot`, and therefore I added this path. Following this, I issue `source devel/setup.bash`  and `roslaunch robotic_moveit_config smp.launch`  and still see the following

```
Resource not found: ur_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/zahid/Desktop/IMPLEMENTATIONS/zahid_test_ws/src/my_test_pkg
ROS path [2]=/home/zahid/Desktop/IMPLEMENTATIONS/zahid_test_ws/src/ur5_moveit_config
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/melodic/
```

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2019-12-10**:
i tried the following

1. adding the following line to the `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
```

2. copying the directory `ur_description` under `/home/zahid/Desktop/IMPLEMENTATIONS/zahid_test_ws/src/ur5_moveit_config/`

But, still the same problem persists.

thanks for your time.

**Comment by [brunvj](https://answers.ros.org/users/50416/brunvj/) on 2020-01-29**:
It would be wonderful if anyone could answer this question, as I am receiving the same results regardless of the ROS paths I indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- The package `ur_description` is not released for meldoic, yet.

  - You can get the source code from https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/tree/melodic-devel .
  - Clone it from github into a folder in your workspaces src folder
- Please never manually edit the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
- Try to work with ONE workspace only. In it:

  - you have one src folder with multiple subfolders, e.g.:

    - `universal_robot` (from the repo above) and also
    - `my_test_pkg` (from the MoveIt setup assistant)
    - There should also be a file  `CMakeLists.txt`, that was generated by `catkin_init_workspace`
  - Remove `devel` and `build` folder,
  - in a clean terminal source only `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`
  - build the workspace
- after this, `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` is sufficient.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anu_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/56640/anu_ros/) on 2020-07-15**:
Im getting the same error;working on ROS melodic.
~/catkin_ws/src/franka_robot/launch$ roslaunch hw2.launch
... logging to /home/anu/.ros/log/80658588-c69f-11ea-8785-080027ad997f/roslaunch-anu-VirtualBox-8095.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Resource not found: franka_robot
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROS path [2]=/home/anu/catkin_ws/src/franka_robot
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Ive edited the ~/.bashrc file:
:~/catkin_ws/src/franka_robot/launch$ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"
/opt/ros/melodic/bin
/usr/lib/ccache
/usr/lib/ccache
/usr/lib/ccache
/usr/lib/ccache
/usr/lib/ccache
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/catkin_ws/src/franka_robot/launch
/catkin_ws/src/franka_robot/launch
/home/anu/catkin_ws/src/franka_robot/launch

Thankyou

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2020-08-04**:
Did you follow everything that is in my answer above?

**Comment by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on 2021-06-25**:
worked thank you so much

**Comment by [zeyno](https://answers.ros.org/users/98813/zeyno/) on 2022-03-05**:
hi, ı tried what you write but did not work

Resource not found: description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file